# The closure of a sum space in $L^2$

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

Let $\Gamma$ and $\Psi$ be probability measures on $(\mathbb{R}, {\cal B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and
construct a product probability space $(\mathbb{R}^2, {\cal B}(\mathbb{R^2}), \Gamma\otimes
\Psi)$.

Consider the following two subspaces  of 
$L^2(\mathbb{R}^2, {\cal B}(\mathbb{R^2}), \Gamma\otimes \Psi)$:

$$
A:=
\left\{f(x) + g(y): f,g  \text{ Borel-m'ble with} 
\int(f(x) + g(y))^2 d\Gamma(x)d\Psi(y)<\infty \right\}.
$$
and
$$
B:=
\left\{f(x) + g(y): f,g  \text{ continuous and bounded} 
 \right\}.
$$

My question: what is the closure of $A$ and $B$, respectively ?

Comment: How do you check that $A$ is a subspace?

Comment: I think that Minkowski's inequality shows that $A$ is linear. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, actually it is even simpler as you can use simply the number inequality $(a+b)^2\leq2(a^2+b^2)$.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that this subspace $A$ is convex?  That could be helpful when considering the closure.

Comment: A is closed, and the closure of B  is A.  Reduce to everything  having mean $0$, which is easy.  With the product measure X, Y are independent so if you have a cauchy seq $f_n + g_n(Y),  \mathbb E(f_n(X) + g_n(Y)-(f_m(X) + g_m(Y))^2 =\mathbb E(f_n(X) -f_m(X))^2  + \mathbb E( g_n(Y)- g_m(Y))^2. f_n, g_n$  are also cauchy etc.